# Como parar uma função Javascript que utiliza setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Eu criei uma função de contador regressivo, que está funcionando corretamente. O único problema é que não consigo interrompe-lá. Fiz todo tipo de adaptação com return e clearInterval(), ela para por um segundo e logo em seguida volta a execução.

Esta é a função:

```
function startTimer() {
        let timeValue = $('#clock').text();
        timeValue = timeValue.split(":");
        let minutes = parseInt(timeValue[0]);
        let seconds = parseInt(timeValue[1]);

        if (minutes > 0 || seconds > 0) {
            if (seconds == 00) {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 59;
            } else {
                seconds--;
            }


            $('#clock').text((minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes) + ':' + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : '0' + seconds));

            pomodoroPercent();
        } else {
            $('#clock').text('00:00');

            pomodoroEnd();
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: O que é `pomodoroEnd`?

Comment: se voce precisa executar a funcao a cada 1 segundo, pode usar o `setInterval()` ao inves do `setTimeout()`. So um detalhe, do jeito que fez acredito que nao tem como interromper mesmo nao

Comment: Eu tentei usar o setInterval(), mas dá algum erro e ele não conta direiro. Em certa de 5 segundo ele chega a 00:00 e reinicia a contagem em loop infinito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o que desejas seja isso:

```js
String.prototype.lpad = function(length, char){
    if(!char){
        char = 0;
    }
    var text = this.toString();
    while(text.length < length){
        text = char.toString() + text;
    }
    return text;
}

var clockPause = false;
function startTimer() {
    if(!clockPause){
        let timeValue = $('#clock').text();
        timeValue = timeValue.split(":");
        let minutes = parseInt(timeValue[0]);
        let seconds = parseInt(timeValue[1]);

        if (minutes > 0 || seconds > 0) {
            if (seconds == 00) {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 59;
            } else {
                seconds--;
            }

            $('#clock').text(minutes.toString().lpad(2) + ':' + seconds.toString().lpad(2));

            //pomodoroPercent();
        } else {
            $('#clock').text('00:00');
            //pomodoroEnd();
        }
    }
}

setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

$('.pause').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clockPause = true;
});

$('.play').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clockPause = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="clock">55:00</h1>
<button class="play">Play</button>
<button class="pause">Pause</button>
```

#### Nota

Eu comentei a parte da chamada se suas funções, pois não sei o que são nem o que fazem.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

So pra te dar uma luz no fiim do tunel pode fazer assim

```
function startTimer() {
    let timeValue = $('#clock').text();
    timeValue = timeValue.split(":");
    let minutes = parseInt(timeValue[0]);
    let seconds = parseInt(timeValue[1]);

    if (minutes > 0 || seconds > 0) {
        if (seconds == 00) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }


        $('#clock').text((minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes) + ':' + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : '0' + seconds));

        pomodoroPercent();
    } else {
        $('#clock').text('00:00');

        pomodoroEnd();
        clearInterval(intervalo); //supondo que seja aqui que queira para o contador
        return;
    }
}

var intervalo = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
```

Comment: Então, quando ele fica em 00:00, ele entra no else e para, esta parte funciona corretamente. Só que eu quero dar uma opção para o usuário parar o timer no meio da execução e isso não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: é so chamar o `clearInterval(intervalo);` em qualquer lugar que quiser, basta que a variavel `intervalo` tenha a referencia do `setInterval()`